# How to get the time required to travel one coordinate to another using Python?

Tags: python

I have Longitude and latitude of two places. How to get the time which is required to travel from one place to another based on the mode of travel(driving, public transport, and walking) using python?

Comment: use a api. Just google `route api` or something similar

Comment: Hi @Sumit, there's no direct module which will give you the solution. You need to use API calls for that. I would suggest you to have a look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro